# mips accessing variable with procedures

Tags: mips, procedure, argument-passing

I've just started to learn MIPS and I have a question about it.Here is my sample code :

```
       .data
var2: .space 201        
var1:  .byte '.'


    .text
main:
        la $a0,var2
        li $a1,201           
        li $v0,8            
        syscall             

        jal foo         

        # code is over.
        li $v0,10 
        syscall

foo:
```

As you can see in the code, I did not assign any register to var1.Now can I use var1 in foo procedure ? Or to be able to use variables,defined in .data segment, outside of main procedure should I assign them to argument registers ? thanks in advance

**EDIT**

As you can see, I've created var2 to store somethings. First of all I read a stdin and store it say $t0 register. What I want to do is that I want to read char by char the stdin and compare it with some chars which are stored in var2,however at the first step of my comparision, var2 will be empty (or has garbage) and I want to know how could I solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say, "Now can I use var1 in foo procedure", it shows that you're still thinking like a high-level language programmer. That's not a bad thing, of course... it's just that assembly is a whole other ball game.

You don't really have "variables". You have memory, and *everyone* has access to it. `var1` isn't a variable, it's just the address of a location in memory. You could store and load data from that memory address from *anywhere* in your assembly code.

Now, keeping that in mind, I don't think your "variable declarations" did what you expected them to. Here's what you did:

- You allocated a block of 201 bytes. This area of memory has not been initialized, so its contents could be anything. The first byte in that block can be accessed (by anyone) by referencing label `var1`.
- You allocated one more byte, and gave it the contents 0x2E (ASCII character '.').
- You called the `syscall` that expects an ASCIIZ string of characters. But you didn't put a '\0' (0x00) terminator anywhere, so the syscall could in theory go on printing characters until the end of memory. (Chances are it didn't because the MARS emulator tends to set memory to 0x00.)

Your other question is, "should I assign them to argument registers". That's still HLL thinking, I think. If you want to use a value that is stored in memory, you *load* it into a register: `lw $t0 var1` gets you the contents of the first *word* starting at address `var1`. If you want to put the value in the register, into the memory location starting at `var1`, you *store* it from a register: `sw $t0 var1`.

Does that help clarify things?

Comment: thanks for clarification. Now I have a totally different question but I'll ask it through editing this question can you also help it ?

Comment: @Eday Not sure if your edited question makes sense. How can you "compare it with some chars which are stored in var2" if var2 hasn't been initialized?